# Facebook business page creation via API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I want to create a facebook business page programatically via their API.

I looked at each of the technologies listed on developer.facebook.com but there is nothing that i can use to create a new page. 
After alot of googling i found out that it seems to be **impossible to create a page programatically**. And i almost gave up, but then i found

https://www.pagemodo.com

Testing their service i see that **they can** actually  create a new one and looking trought their javascript files it seesm they do it on the backend.

After reading some more i found about the new facebook business API ( https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/businessmanager ), and i got nowhere with that either.

I am on the verge of believing that it's impossible, but having the working example on pagemodo makes me unable to give up :D .

**[Possible Solution 1]**

Another ideea that i have on how to achieve this is to

- manually create a number of template pages on my account (not published).
- add that user as an admin to one of the pages via API [*]
- remove myself from the administration via API [*]
- edit the page title/description/etc. via API
- publish the page via API

For the normal users, it will look like the page was created auto,so this could work. But the problem is that i couldn't find anything in the API to make the [*] operations work.

Any help appreciated

Comment: I am pretty sure there is no API for that, at least not a publicly available one. And if pagemodo don’t have a special deal with FB in that regard, then they are probably just doing that by “faking” real requests that would take place if a user was creating a new page actually using the UI facebook.com provides.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible. You need to get your Facebook App *whitelisted* to get access to page creation apis.

Comment: I looked at the extra features you can get as a white-listed app, but there isn't none that provides me access to that, or did i miss something? @Zain

Comment: Its probably not documented. After it's whitelisted, you'll be able to make a graph api PUT request to /me/accounts and create pages on the fly.

Comment: @ZainZafar Do you have any example of that ? I tried to do this without success for a while... Thanks !

Comment: Nop.... I asked a company that do the job with success, but they cannot tell me how :/

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to create business pages via the public Facebook API.

Comment: I agree with you, it's not possible via the public API. I believe they do it like @CBore said (using something like a bot to create a new page  using facebook interface, but they don't ask for any creditentials, so instead, i think they transfer it to you)